# How to get id from database that's equal DataGridView1 selected row id cell value in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, sqlite, datagridview

How to get id from database that's equal DataGridView1 selected row id cell value in c#?

I have this code in vb.net, and now I have to convert it to c#.

my code

```
DataGridView1.Item(0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value
```

Comment: Add a `;` to the end of the line.

Comment: You'll probably need another big change: rename `DataGridView1` to `dataGridView1` and maybe cast `.Value` to the actual type. You can also use `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;`

Comment: @Jimi no awards for naming, but it would not be necessary to rename the grid.

Comment: @Crowcoder  Well, if you follow/enforce the camelCase rule when naming your objects, you'll have to. Not strictly necessary, but it's nonetheless a naming convention in C#. I don't allow a solution to compile if this rule is violated (StackOverflow users also pushed it).

Comment: @Jimi I think that is an admirable rule to enforce but style-wise I would personally find the generic name `dataGridView1` worse than a casing violation.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, of course, that name is commonly used just in sample code snippets, so it's more clear what the object is just looking at its (default) name.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a duplicate from [Getting the first cell from selected row from DataGridView in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734357/getting-the-first-cell-from-selected-row-from-datagridview-in-c-sharp)

getting the first cell value from selected row would be:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```